# Change pop/smtp settings for exchange server 2007

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, pop3

I spend couple of hours on Microsoft exchange server and I couldn't figure out how I can change the smtp server/port and the incoming mail server. Keeping in mind we rely on a shared hosting for this purpose. Basically I'm using hostmonster for this purpose:

Outgoing Mail Server: (SSL): host216.hostmonster.com (server requires authentication) port 465
Incoming Mail Server: (SSL): host216.hostmonster.com IMAP: port 993, POP: port 995

Does anyone have any experience with such application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange doesnt have POP3 support. The only solution was to use a third party addon: http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm

Answer (score 2):

On-premise Exchange doesn't have an out-of-box function to scrape the POP/IMAP data out of your host. You can relay through them, but, if you wanted the POP/IMAP mail to be retrieved by Exchange and cached in local mailboxes, you'd have to look for a third party add-on.

Comment: do you have any idea what third party add-on out their might be useful? I guess you understood my question perfectly.